# JSON.net deserialize array of arrays

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My RootObject

```
       [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [JsonProperty("error")]
        public ErrosHelper Error {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [JsonProperty("resource")]
        public List<List<int>> Resource {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

Json response.

> {"status":"success","resource":{"1":{"1":"30","2":"23","3":"43"},"2":{"1":"34","2":"54","3":"32"},"3":{"1":"56","2":"43","3":"39"},"4":{"1":"23","2":"32","3":"31"},"5":{"1":"34","2":"37","3":"29"},"6":{"1":"38","2":"34","3":"45"},"7":{"1":"67","2":"53","3":"67"},"8":{"1":"45","2":"23","3":"78"},"9":{"1":"54","2":"44","3":"56"},"10":{"1":"46","2":"23","3":"45"},"11":{"1":"77","2":"56","3":"78"},"12":{"1":"34","2":"21","3":"65"},"13":{"1":"46","2":"23","3":"45"},"14":{"1":"77","2":"56","3":"78"},"15":{"1":"34","2":"21","3":"65"},"16":{"1":"46","2":"23","3":"45"},"17":{"1":"77","2":"56","3":"78"},"18":{"1":"34","2":"21","3":"65"},"19":{"1":"46","2":"23","3":"45"},"20":{"1":"77","2":"56","3":"78"}}}

I have response , that give me Json string. How do I can deserialise this string to my object?

Comment: Edited. Read question below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your object is wrong. 
The JSON you are showing does not have a list of lists of int, but rather dictionary of dictionaries.

If you change it to

```
public class Root {
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [JsonProperty("resource")]
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> Resource {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

It will deserialize correctly using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);`

Comment: Thanks u very much.This exactly what i`m looking for.